# How to display empty rows in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query where I need to know the number of records for each state for a particular column. I need states with zero records to show up on my results. Here is my query it only shows states that have a record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    StateAbbr, count (*)
FROM
    DataWarehouse
WHERE 
    FiscalYear = 2017
    AND MaltreatmentSetCode != '999' 
    AND MaltreatmentSetCode != '' 
    AND StateAbbr IN (SELECT DISTINCT StateAbbr
                      FROM DataWarehouse
                      WHERE (NOT MaltreatmentSetCode = '999')
                        AND FiscalYear = 2017)
GROUP BY 
    StateAbbr
ORDER BY 
    StateAbbr ASC
```

Comment: Where can we find the list of all possible states ? Also the `DISTINCT StateAbbr` does not make sense in you query since you are already using `GROUP BY StateAbbr`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to select from a 'State' table to get the list of states, then join to your count to get the totals and use a coalesce to substitute 0 when there is no data returned from the datawarehouse.  Simple example below:

```
create table #state (state varchar(1))

create table #datawarehouse (state varchar(1), data int)


insert into #state 
    values   ('a')
            ,('b')
            ,('c')
            ,('d')

insert into #datawarehouse(state, data)
    values ('a', 1)
            ,('a',2)
            ,('a',3)
            ,('b',1)

SELECT State.State, COALESCE(DataWarehouse.c, 0)
FROM   #State state
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT  State, Count(*) c
                            FROM    #DataWareHouse datawarehouse
                            GROUP BY State) Datawarehouse
              ON   State.State = DataWareHouse.State
```

Comment: This won't work, every state without an entry will have a count of 1.

Comment: Thanks user1178830, I have corrected the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: If you count a column that is null (datawarehouse.state) instead of * ...

Answer (score 0):

If all values of `StateAbbr` that we want to return appear in rows in `DataWarehouse` table, we can use conditional aggregation.

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT dw.StateAbbr
     , SUM(CASE WHEN dw.FiscalYear = 2017 AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '999' AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
  FROM DataWarehouse dw
 GROUP BY dw.StateAbbr
 ORDER BY dw.StateAbbr ASC
```

Note that for each row, the CASE expression is going to be evaluated, returning either 0 or 1, and the SUM() aggregate will add the 1s and 0s up to get us a count.

If there's values of `StateAbbr` that should be returned by that are not in the `DateWarehouse` table, then we need a rowsource for those values. (Frequently, these values are in "dimension" tables in a data mart.)

Assuming `Abbr` is unique in the `dwstate` table... if this query returns the distinct list of state abbr we need to return:

```
SELECT s.Abbr
  FROM dwstate s
ORDER BY s.Abbr
```

Then we could do something like this:

```
SELECT s.Abbr  AS StateAbbr 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN dw.FiscalYear = 2017 AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '999' AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
  FROM dwstate s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN DataWarehouse dw
    ON dw.StateAbbr = s.Abbr
 GROUP BY s.Abbr
 ORDER BY s.Abbr ASC
```

---

These examples omit the bit about the subquery; it's not clear (to me) which part of the specification that part is meant to satisfy.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT StateAbbr
      FROM DataWarehouse
     WHERE (NOT MaltreatmentSetCode = '999' )
       AND FiscalYear = 2017
```

If that subquery is meant to return the set of StateAbbr that we are supposed to return, then we can use that as a rowsource in place of `dwstate` ...

```
SELECT s.Abbr  AS StateAbbr 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN dw.FiscalYear = 2017 AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '999' AND dw.MaltreatmentSetCode != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
  FROM ( -- unique list of state abbreviations 
         SELECT n.StateAbbr AS Abbr
           FROM DataWarehouse n
          WHERE (NOT n.MaltreatmentSetCode = '999' )
            AND n.FiscalYear = 2017
          GROUP BY n.StateAbbr
       ) s
  LEFT 
  JOIN DataWarehouse dw
    ON dw.StateAbbr = s.Abbr
 GROUP BY s.Abbr
 ORDER BY s.Abbr ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all states, left join your data to it. Count.

```
SELECT allstates.StateAbbr, count (data.StateAbbr)
FROM 
  (select distinct StateAbbr from datawarehouse) allstates 
  LEFT JOIN
  DataWarehouse data
  ON 
    allstates.stateabbr = data.stateabbr and
    data.FiscalYear = 2017 and
    data.MaltreatmentSetCode NOT IN('999', '') 

GROUP BY allstates.StateAbbr
ORDER BY allstates.StateAbbr ASC
```